# Vue: Importing JSON requesting loader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I am trying to import a JSON file into a Single Vue Component and when I build, I get this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1980 while parsing near '...647 25 49.981 25Z",
}
'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

I am using Laravel Mix and see a webpack.config file at `node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` but there are no configurable options there.

Comment: How are you importing this json? Using `import` or `require`?

Comment: @Giovane `import icons from './icons.json';`

Comment: The error message is indicating that there is an invalid character, did you check for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an extra comma in the end of the json, please remove it and try again.